# Include PHP File in PHP.ini

Tags: php

I need to include a php library in my php.ini so it can be used for all the sites on server. How can I do this? Currently I have added this to my php.ini

```
include_path = ".:/Users/myname/Sites/edr/includeroot/application_top.php"
```

But it doesn't appear to be loading. Ami doing something wrong?

Comment: try `auto_prepend_file` http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: Please dont use `auto_prepend_file` only  for including the page header: `application_top.php`. Thats realy bad practise. Try to bootstrap your application and load the lib in that boostrap.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`include_path` directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) is not meant for that (emphasis mine):

> Specifies **a list of directories** where the require, include,
>   fopen(), file(), readfile() and file_get_contents() functions look for
>   files. The format is like the system's PATH environment variable: a
>   list of directories separated with a colon in Unix or semicolon in
>   Windows.
>
> PHP considers each entry in the include path separately when looking
>   for files to include. It will check the first path, and if it doesn't
>   find it, check the next path, until it either locates the included
>   file or returns with a warning or an error. You may modify or set your
>   include path at runtime using set_include_path().

You want [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file):

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the
>   main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require
>   function, so include_path is used.

Yet I strongly suggest you avoid setting it for the entire system. The directive is `PHP_INI_PERDIR` thus can be changed in [several other places](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `auto_prepend_file` or `auto_append_file`:

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the
>   main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require
>   function, so include_path is used.

You can read the documentation about them [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).